# Two Table SQL review

Tags: sql, oracle

!(https://i.stack.imgur.com/loBUE.jpg)

A pic of the tables is above.

3. List the youngest customer.
4. List all the orders (ordereID, order date, amount) along with customer details.

I am struggling with these two questions.

Comment: This is not a "do my homework for me" site.  We can help, just not do the whole thing for you.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have completed question 2 which is : list the total orders placed from each city.

Answer (score 2):

Can't see table name from your pic?

3. List the youngest customer. Try something like this but replact the [top table from pic] to the name of the actual table.

   ```
   select custFName, custLName, MIN(Date) from 
   (select 
   *, cast(DateofBirth as date) as date
   from customers) a group by 1,2;
   ```

OR

```
Select TOP 1 * from customers ORDER BY dateofbirth asc
```

4.List all the orders (ordereID, order date, amount) along with customer details.

```
select a.*, b.custLname, b.custFname, b.dateofbirth, b.custcity from
orders a 
left join customers b on b.custid = a.custid
```

Comment: I tried this and got error at line 1 missing expression.



Top Table name is - Customers, my apologies I didn't realize it was cut off

Comment: then try this maybe at the end: group by 1,2

Comment: For #4 I used 

WHERE a.custID = b.custID instead of LEFT JOIN and that worked.

Still not able to get #3 to work :/ Anyway you can post it as SQL code like you did for #4 that formatting helped

Comment: What kind of SQL syntax is this?

Comment: We are using oracle, a lot of syntax I have seen elsewhere is too advanced so that is why I Normally post...

It seems like we just need to use MIN to get the youngest customer and only need data from the top table (customers), but every query I try is failing..

Comment: I also am struggling with this question...

List the customers name with the least total amount of orders

Thanks Berra2k

Comment: try to use this: Select TOP 1 * from customers ORDER BY date asc